# Client Certificates for nginx upstream not working

Tags: nginx, openssl, mqtt

I followed this guide as closely as possible for nginx:
https://fardog.io/blog/2017/12/30/client-side-certificate-authentication-with-nginx/

This was the result

```
 stream{
        upstream broker {
            server 10.110.0.4:1883 fail_timeout=10s max_fails=1;
            server 10.110.0.3:1883 fail_timeout=10s max_fails=1;
            server 10.110.0.6:1883 fail_timeout=10s max_fails=1;
        }
    
        server {
    
            error_log /var/log/nginx/mqtt_error.log debug;
                        
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mqtt.domain.com/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mqtt.domain.com/server.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /root/clientca/ca.crt;
    
    ssl_verify_client on;  
    
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
            listen mqtt.domain.com:8883 ssl;
    
    proxy_pass broker;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        }
    
    }
```

I am getting errors in nginx when I try to connect the mqtt client:

```
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: accept on 188.166.22.84:8883, ready: 1
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: posix_memalign: 0000563822D6D490:256 @16
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 accept: 11.65.81.90:51256 fd:3
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: posix_memalign: 0000563822D6D6F0:256 @16
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [info] 780885#780885: *5 client 11.65.81.90:51256 connected to 111.166.22.84:8883
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 posix_memalign: 0000563822D6D930:256 @16
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 generic phase: 0
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 generic phase: 1
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 generic phase: 2
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 tcp_nodelay
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 posix_memalign: 0000563822D6D820:256 @16
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 SSL_get_error: 2
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80002001
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 event timer add: 3: 60000:9742886896
2021/04/28 07:34:20 [debug] 780885#780885: accept() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 SSL handshake handler: 0
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 SSL_get_error: 2
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 SSL handshake handler: 0
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 SSL_get_error: 1
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [info] 780885#780885: *5 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:SSL alert number 48) while SSL handshaking, client: 11.65.81.90, server: 111.166.22.84:8883
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 finalize stream session: 500
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 stream log handler
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 close stream connection: 3
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 event timer del: 3: 9742886896
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 reusable connection: 0
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 free: 0000563822D6D490, unused: 64
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 free: 0000563822D6D6F0, unused: 80
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 free: 0000563822D6D930, unused: 80
2021/04/28 07:34:25 [debug] 780885#780885: *5 free: 0000563822D6D820, unused: 136
```

I have very little experience in the server side

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1056351/nginx-tlsv1-alert-unknown-cassl-alert-number-48 similar issue, but not sure how the solution applies

Answer (score 0):

https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/sign-server-and-client-certificates.html#deploy-the-certificate

So, I ended up solving it with the above link. Here is the list of problems and solutions:

1. I had letsencrypt for the domain, and the client keys as in this link. Mosquitto was passing the ca-chain and verifying first the SSL from letsencrypt, it failed
2. the root ca.cert.pem I guess did not include all the needed data, so I used the intermediate ca-chain.cert.pem
3. mosquitto needed the --insecure flag (this would not be relevant if I used a paid SSL such as in this example: https://www.ssltrust.com/help/setup-guides/client-certificate-authentication